# Maven Build Failure Blue Ocean plugin for Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, node-modules

I am trying to build Blue Ocean Jenkins Plugin as i am planning to make a few minor UI changes in the landing page.

I am running `mvn clean install` as in the repo README.md.
I bumped into an issue running the above command. Below is the build log. Any advice will be helpful. Many thanks.

```
[INFO] [13:12:57] Browserify bundle processing error
[INFO] [13:12:57]       error: Error: Cannot find module '..    stempjundleStartup.js' from 'C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\target\js-bundle-src'
[ERROR] C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\@jenkins-cd\js-builder\internal\bundlegen.js:289
[INFO]     at C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
[ERROR]                 throw new Error('Browserify bundle processing error. See above for details.');
[INFO]     at process (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
[ERROR]                 ^
[INFO]     at ondir (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
[ERROR]
[INFO]     at load (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
[ERROR] Error: Browserify bundle processing error. See above for details.
[INFO]     at onex (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
[ERROR]     at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\@jenkins-cd\js-builder\internal\bundlegen.js:289:23)
[INFO]     at C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
[ERROR]     at Readable.emit (events.js:182:13)
[INFO]     at C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
[ERROR]     at Labeled.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\read-only-stream\index.js:28:44)
[INFO]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
[ERROR]     at Labeled.emit (events.js:182:13)
[ERROR]     at Labeled.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\stream-splicer\index.js:130:18)
[ERROR]     at Labeled.emit (events.js:182:13)
[ERROR]     at Deps.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\stream-splicer\index.js:130:18)
[ERROR]     at Deps.emit (events.js:182:13)
[ERROR]     at C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:361:30
[ERROR]     at onresolve (C:\workspace\blueocean-plugin\blueocean-core-js\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:179:25)
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 1
[ERROR] npm ERR! @jenkins-cd/blueocean-core-js@1.10.4 mvnbuild: `gulp lint build bundle`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the @jenkins-cd/blueocean-core-js@1.10.4 mvnbuild script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     C:\Users\nbalakrishna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-21T07_42_57_865Z-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Blue Ocean Parent 1.23.3-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Blue Ocean Parent .................................. SUCCESS [ 16.045 s]
[INFO] Jenkins Design Language ............................ SUCCESS [03:05 min]
[INFO] Blue Ocean Core JS ................................. FAILURE [01:13 min]
[INFO] Common API for Blue Ocean .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST API for Blue Ocean ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] i18n for Blue Ocean ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Web for Blue Ocean ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pipeline SCM API for Blue Ocean .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JWT for Blue Ocean ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Implementation for Blue Ocean ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Events API for Blue Ocean .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Dashboard for Blue Ocean ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Personalization for Blue Ocean ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Config API for Blue Ocean .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GitHub Pipeline for Blue Ocean ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Bitbucket Pipeline for Blue Ocean .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Blue Ocean Pipeline Editor ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JIRA Integration for Blue Ocean .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Blue Ocean ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Blue Ocean Executor Info ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:42 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-21T13:12:58+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:npm (npm mvnbuild) on project blueocean-core-js: Failed to run task: 'npm run mvnbuild' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :blueocean-core-js
```

It fails to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:npm (npm mvnbuild) on project blueocean-core-js. Above is the build log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted the question in Jenkins User Experience Google group and learnt that Blue Ocean doesn't compile in Windows. As suggested, I am going to try running things in WSL1 or WSL2, but not native Windows.